# How to create a custom angular-moment filter

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I want to create a custom angular moment filter to show only the years passed from a specefic birth date.

For example I have a value 1990-06-05, it should show 25.

I'm using :   `<time am-time-ago="player.birthday"></time>`

But it shows `it's been 25 years`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular `amTimeAgo` filter takes three arguments:

- value
- preprocess
- suffix

> as per the [momentjs#fromNow](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) implementation.

If the last passed parameter to the filter is `true`, you would change the output from:

`it's been 25 years` to `25 years`.

If that doesn't cut it, you could create your own filter like so:

```
.filter('straightUpYear', function (amTimeAgoFilter) {
  return function (value) {
    return amTimeAgoFilter(value, false, true).replace(/years/, '');
  }
});
```

Then use it as such:

```
<time>{{ player.birthday | straightUpYear }}</time>
```

**[jsbin showcasing the result](http://jsbin.com/wowaneguhi/1/edit?html,js,output)**

---

A thing of note; You're asking for a `filter`, but in your example you are using the *directive* version of `amTimeAgo`.

If the goal is to create a directive, please edit your question to specify it as such and I will modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which is better a directive or a filter ?

Comment: Well, a filter is arguably more reusable as you can use it within your controllers and services. A directive on the other hand is more powerful in terms of DOM manipulation, and you *could* use the filter inside a directive. It depends on how much juice you need :)

Comment: And I would also note; Using a filter *inside* your controller **is** faster than using it in the view with the pipe `|` notation, as the filter will evaluate twice when using the pipe. But just once when called from the controller.